# Airthematic operations of Big real Numbers, 30 to 40 digits long

Tags: java, arrays

Airthematic operation on Big numbers up to 30 to 40 digits long, some of the related material on internet is not really related. any idea how can we do this.

Comment: What's wrong with `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Can you give example of what u r trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right under your nose, in the standard Java API.

You should use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for this purpose.